# Dynamically map XML elements to JSON fields in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, mapping

I have an XML document, and I also have a mapping configuration that specifies how to map XML elements to JSON fields. The XML structure and the mapping can change, and I need a way to dynamically generate JSON based on the XML and the mapping.

**XML Example:**

```xml
<personData>
  <fname>John</fname>
  <lname>Doe</lname>
  <years>30</years>
  <email>johndoe@example.com</email>
  <residence>
    <street>123 Main St</street>
    <city>Anytown</city>
    <state>CA</state>
  </residence>
  <interests>
    <hobby>reading</hobby>
    <hobby>hiking</hobby>
  </interests>
  <contacts>
    <friend>
      <name>Alice</name>
      <years>28</years>
    </friend>
    <friend>
      <name>Bob</name>
      <years>32</years>
    </friend>
  </contacts>
</personData>
```

**Mapping Example:**

```json
{
  "person.firstName": "personData.fname",
  "person.lastName": "personData.lname",
  "person.age": "personData.years",
  "person.email": "personData.email",
  "person.address.street": "personData.residence.street",
  "person.address.city": "personData.residence.city",
  "person.address.state": "personData.residence.state",
  "person.hobbies": "personData.interests.hobby",
  "person.friends.name": "personData.contacts.friend.name",
  "person.friends.age": "personData.contacts.friend.years"
}
```

I want to write C# code that can parse the XML and use the mapping configuration to generate a JSON object dynamically. The challenge is that the XML structure and mapping can vary, so I need a solution that can adapt to these changes.

I would like to store each field or subfield mapping in a separate row within the mapping structure. This approach offers the advantage that if a new sub-subfield is introduced within a subfield, we can easily add it immediately after the mapping for the parent subfield.

Could someone please provide guidance or sample code on how to achieve this dynamic XML to JSON mapping in C#? Any libraries or techniques that can help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**Desired Output (if I pass the above XML and Mapping):**

```json
{
  "person": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 30,
    "email": "johndoe@example.com",
    "address": {
      "street": "123 Main St",
      "city": "Anytown",
      "state": "CA"
    },
    "hobbies": ["reading", "hiking"],
    "friends": [
      {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 28
      },
      {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 32
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wanted to implement the Actionstep API. I wanted to create new new action inside the Actionstep. [Click here](https://actionstep.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/API/pages/40108259/Action+Create) to see the documentation. In order to call action to create api, first it we have to do the GET call to fetch the JSON format. Then we can do post using that JSON format to create an action.

So, I am going to create an endpoint that will accept the Xml data, will get the JSON from action create GET call. Wanted to map my xml data with the JSON which I am going to receive from Actionstep and wanted to submit it back via POST. For that we require mapping, which I will store into database and make it user configurable. So, in future, if some new field will be introduced, it will automatically map based on the mapping available into the database. Please note that I don't know what type of xml they are going to pass and what type of JSON will be. It only knows by admin. Who will setup the mapping. based on that will fill the required JSON.

I need a solution in .NET C# language.

I attempted to address the problem and created a corresponding fiddle, accessible at https://dotnetfiddle.net/ypMskz.

Within that fiddle, I achieved success in binding singular fields at any level, including arrays of primitive types such as integers, strings, and so on. However, the primary challenge I'm encountering pertains to lists of custom objects. As evidenced in the fiddle, the following lines in the mapping are currently commented out:

```cs
//{"Person.Friend.Name", "personData.contacts.friend.name"},
//{"Person.Friend.Years", "personData.contacts.friend.years"}
```

I'm encountering challenges with those fields, which represent a custom object.

The above line pertains to a custom object array. The potential solution should be recursive, as it's possible that one object array might contain another object array as well.

Comment: I'm looking for custom logic. How is that helpful to me?

Comment: What is your question about?  When you have an XML how to convert it to Json or  when you have    a Json how to convert it to XML? I can not see any sense in this  at all, it looks like a high school home work

Comment: I edited my question to make my requirement more clear. Appreciate any feedback if there is any confusion on above

Answer (score -1):

Here is a powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.txt'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$json = Get-Content -Path $inputFilename | ConvertFrom-Json 

$personData = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('personData'))

$firstName = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('fname'),$json.person.firstname)
$personData.Add($firstName)

$lastName = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('lname'),$json.person.lastname)
$personData.Add($lastName)

$years = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('years'),$json.person.age)
$personData.Add($years)

$email = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('email'),$json.person.email)
$personData.Add($email)

$street = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('street'),$json.person.address.street)
$personData.Add($street)

$city = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('city'),$json.person.address.city)
$personData.Add($city)

$state = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('state'),$json.person.address.state)
$personData.Add($state)

$interest = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('interests'))
$personData.Add($interest)

foreach($hobby in $json.person.hobbies)
{
   $hobby = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('hobby'),$hobby)
   $interest.Add($hobby)
}

$contacts = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('contacts'))
$personData.Add($contacts)

foreach($friend in $json.person.friends)
{
   $xFriend = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('friend'))
   $contacts.Add($xFriend)

   $name = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('name'),$friend.name)
   $xFriend.Add($name)

   $age = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('years'),$friend.age)
   $xFriend.Add($age)

}

$personData.Save($outputFilename)
```

Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<personData>
  <fname>John</fname>
  <lname>Doe</lname>
  <years>30</years>
  <email>johndoe@example.com</email>
  <street>123 Main St</street>
  <city>Anytown</city>
  <state>CA</state>
  <interests>
    <hobby>reading</hobby>
    <hobby>hiking</hobby>
  </interests>
  <contacts>
    <friend>
      <name>Alice</name>
      <years>28</years>
    </friend>
    <friend>
      <name>Bob</name>
      <years>32</years>
    </friend>
  </contacts>
</personData>
```

Comment: As I added tag C#, wanted solution in C#

Comment: PS is written in Net Library.  Code above is really c# code except for the importing of the json file.  The rest of the code is using the System.Xml.Linq library.  I didn't want to use the c# json serializer which is not a standard Net/Core library.

Comment: Additionally, I just added example of JSON and XML. It is not exactly the same. It might change at run time. Because my API accepts both JSON input from the API and XML input from the parameter.  My JSON and xml cab be anything. It is strickly depends on mapping

Comment: By the way, thank you @jdweng for your active participation. I am really stuck into the same and actively looking for solution

Comment: I don't see you changes.  I don't know how to make this dynamic especially with the xml nesting.  The powershell json deserializer is better than in c# so I really do not want to convert code to c#.